# Any way to get split_regex to accept a const string as input?

Tags: c++, boost, text-parsing

Following [code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/23NBLNBVpyauvhvg#wandbox-resultwindow-code-body-2) compilation implodes with deep template error stack if I try to make string input const, but I do not understand why it should be mutable.

From thinking about algorithm const should be fine, also I checked that the argument is not modified after function call.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string_regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string str("helloABboostABworld");
    static const boost::regex re("AB");
    std::vector<boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator> > results;
    boost::split_regex(results, boost::make_iterator_range(str.begin(),
    str.end()), re);
    for (const auto& range: results){
        std::cout << std::string(range.begin(), range.end()) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Any way to make this code work with `const std::string str;`?

Comment: what you call "deep template error stack" is just a warning. The code compiles and if you scroll down you can see its output in your link

Comment: If you have `const std::string str` then I think you'll need to declare `results` as `std::vector<boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator>>` (note `const_iterator` rather than `iterator`).

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 like I said to see the error you need to try to make the str const

Comment: @G.M. yes, that solves it. :) Maybe you want to make it an answer

Comment: better post the code that has the problem not code that is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment, if the `std::string` being searched is `const` then the iterator type used in the results must be the associated `const_iterator` type for the container being searched.  Hence if the string being searched is...

```
const std::string str("helloABboostABworld");
```

Then the results container should be...

```
std::vector<boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator>> results;
```

So the complete example becomes...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string_regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    const std::string str("helloABboostABworld");
    static const boost::regex re("AB");
    std::vector<boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator>> results;
    boost::split_regex(results, boost::make_iterator_range(str.begin(),
    str.end()), re);
    for (const auto& range: results){
        std::cout << std::string(range.begin(), range.end()) << std::endl;
    }
}
```